# Number of similar pixels on a loop arround some pixel

Tags: image-processing

I defined a command **ŠtejTakePiksleOkol**, that counts the number of pixels on a square loop arround some pixel, that have similar normalized RGB.
If the square loop would go over the edge of the picture it only takes the loop bounded by the edge of the image.

```
ŠtejTakePiksleOkol[slikapiksli_, baarva_, \[Epsilon]_, sred_, 
  polm_] := {
   resx = Length[slikapiksli[[1]]  ];
   resy = Length[slikapiksli];
   \[CapitalDelta]naštetih = 0;
   
   (*edges of the loop*)
   levo = If[polm >= sred[[2]], 1, sred[[2]] - polm  ];
   desno = If[sred[[2]] + polm > resx, resx, sred[[2]] + polm ];
   gor = If[polm >= sred[[1]], 1, sred[[1]] - polm];
   dol = If[sred[[1]] + polm > resy, resy, sred[[1]] + polm];
   (*pixels we have to check*)
   kpnk = If[polm == 0,
     {sred},
     Flatten[
      {
       Table[
        {dol, x},
        {x, levo, desno - 1}],
       Table[
        {y, desno},
        {y, gor + 1, dol}],
       Table[
        {gor, x},
        {x, levo + 1, desno}],
       Table[
        {y, levo},
        {y, gor, dol - 1}]
       },
      1]
     ];
   (
      {i1, i2} = #;
      If[
        Normalize[baarva].Normalize[slikapiksli[[i1, i2]]  ] > 
         1 - \[Epsilon],
        \[CapitalDelta]naštetih++;
        ]
      ) & /@ kpnk;
   \[CapitalDelta]naštetih
   }[[1]]
```

Where **slikapiksli** is the image data, **baarva** is the wanted RGB, **$\epsilon$** is sth like the allowed difference, **sred** is the middle pixel and **polm** is the max 'radius' of the loop.

Now let's make a simple image

```
slikakrogca = Image[
  Table[
   If[i1^2 + i2^2 < 100^2, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}],
   {i1, -300, 500},{i2, -700, 500}]
  ]
```

[image]

Now apply the function for radius polm=15

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 ŠtejTakePiksleOkol[ImageData[slikakrogca], {0, 1, 1}, .001, {3, 40}, 15]
]
```

```
{0.0134907, 0}
```

The same for polm=16

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 ŠtejTakePiksleOkol[ImageData[slikakrogca], {0, 1, 1}, .001, {3, 40}, 16]
]
```

```
{0.536426, 0}
```

And for polm=700

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 ŠtejTakePiksleOkol[ImageData[slikakrogca], {0, 1, 1}, .001, {3, 40}, 700]
]
```

```
{0.583814, 185}
```

Basically it slows down horribly from 15 to 16. Why is that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a version of your code mostly to understand it. But the timing issue seems to have disappeared as well, so I will post it. If I have time later I might try to optimize it further.

```
getPixels[imageData_, center_, 0] := {center}
getPixels[imageData_, center_, radius_] := Module[{
   resx = Length[imageData[[1]]],
   resy = Length[imageData],
   columnStart,
   columnEnd,
   rowStart,
   rowEnd
   },
  columnStart = If[
    radius >= center[[2]],
    1,
    center[[2]] - radius
    ];
  columnEnd = If[
    center[[2]] + radius > resx,
    resx,
    center[[2]] + radius
    ];
  rowStart = If[
    radius >= center[[1]],
    1,
    center[[1]] - radius
    ];
  rowEnd = If[
    center[[1]] + radius > resy,
    resy,
    center[[1]] + radius
    ];
  Flatten[{
    Table[{rowEnd, x}, {x, columnStart, columnEnd - 1}],
    Table[{y, columnEnd}, {y, rowStart + 1, rowEnd}],
    Table[{rowStart, x}, {x, columnStart + 1, columnEnd}],
    Table[{y, columnStart}, {y, rowStart, rowEnd - 1}]
    }, 1]
  ]

countSimilarPixels[imageData_, rgbValue_, allowedDifference_, center_,
    radius_] := Total@Boole@MapThread[
     Normalize[rgbValue].Normalize[imageData[[#, #2]]] > 1 - allowedDifference &,
     Transpose@getPixels[imageData, center, radius]
     ];

testImage = Image[Table[If[i1^2 + i2^2 < 100^2, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}], {i1, -300, 500}, {i2, -700, 500}]];

AbsoluteTiming[countSimilarPixels[ImageData[testImage], {0, 1, 1}, .001, {3, 40}, 50]]

(* Out: {0.012622, 0} *)
```

## Second look

I had another look at the function `getPixels` and made it a bit more readable:

```
getPixels[imageData_, center_, 0] := {center}
getPixels[imageData_, {row_, col_}, radius_] := Module[{
   nrOfColumns,
   nrOfRows,
   columnStart,
   columnEnd,
   rowStart,
   rowEnd
   },
  {nrOfRows, nrOfColumns} = Dimensions[imageData]~Take~2;
  columnStart = Max[1, col - radius];
  columnEnd = Min[nrOfColumns, col + radius];
  rowStart = Max[1, row - radius];
  rowEnd = Min[nrOfRows, row + radius];
  Join[
   Table[{rowEnd, c}, {c, columnStart, columnEnd - 1}],
   Table[{r, columnEnd}, {r, rowStart + 1, rowEnd}],
   Table[{rowStart, c}, {c, columnStart + 1, columnEnd}],
   Table[{r, columnStart}, {r, rowStart, rowEnd - 1}]
   ]
  ]
```

And alternative way of writing `countSimilarPixels` is

```
countSimilarPixels[imageData_, referenceColor_, allowedDifference_, center_, radius_] := Module[
  {pixels, colors, similarity},
  pixels = getPixels[imageData, center, radius];
  colors = Normalize /@ Extract[imageData, pixels];
  similarity = colors.Normalize[referenceColor];
  Total@UnitStep[similarity - (1 - allowedDifference)]
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I'll use this command to get pixels of a colored dot on the image by kind of scanning outwards from a guess point. With that I'll track drawn dots on symple paper airplanes footage and compute the data about their motion in 3D.

Comment: @GalZoidberg Sounds interesting! I like those types of projects. I took another look at it and made some additional updates to the functions. Maybe it will help, maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it turns out, that if i replace last `(...)&/@kpnk` with `Do[...,{i,Length[kpnk]}]` it works normally

```
Do[
  If[Normalize[baarva].Normalize[
      slikapiksli[[kpnk[[i, 1]], kpnk[[i, 2]]   ]]  ] > 1 - \[Epsilon],
   \[CapitalDelta]naštetih++;
   \[CapitalDelta]vsotatakih += slikapiksli[[i1, i2]];
   \[CapitalDelta]vsotakord += {i1, i2};
   ],
  {i, Length[kpnk]}];
```

```
{0.0143393, 0}
```

I don't know why `Map` fails, but now it works